# One or no smallest element on a partial order

Tags: elementary-set-theory, solution-verification

Suppose we have some partial order R on a set A, and B is a subset of A. With partial we mean a relation which is reflexive, transitive and anti-symmetric. With anti-symmetric we mean that if there exists a pair aRb and bRa where a and b are some arbitrary elements in R then a = b.

The following question is now posed:
Suppose B has a smallest element, show there there is either 1 or no smallest element. More specifically, the R-smallest element of B.

The smallest element is defined as: given some arbitrary element of B named x the pair bRx exists.

I have written the following proof:
Suppose more then 1 smallest element exists, we shall call them b1 (element of B) and b2 (element of B). We note that b1 does not equal b2 because we are talking about 2 smallest elements. For them to both be a smallest elements the pairs (b1, b2) and (b2, b1) must exist. However this leads to a contradiction, since a partial order must be anti-symmetric and b1 does not equal b2.

This proof seems quite short compared to the one that is given in my book (Velleman how to prove it). But I wonder if this is sufficient? Any feedback is highly appreciated!

Comment: IMV your short proof is okay.

Comment: Thank you for the feedback @drhab